# Why can't I set this member variable inside a derived class's constructor?

Tags: c++

I have a class `Product` which has a `price` member:

```
class Product {
  float price;

public:
  Product(float price);
};
```

I also have a class `PerishableProduct` which publicly inherits from `Product`:

```
class PerishableProduct : public Product {
  Date expirationDate;

public:
  PerishableProduct(float price, const Date& expirationDate);
};
```

In the constructor for `PerishableProduct`, I'm trying to set the `price` member:

```
PerishableProduct::PerishableProduct(float price, const Date& expirationDate)
    : Product(float()) {
  this->expirationDate = expirationDate;
  this->price = price;
}
```

When I try to compile this program, I get errors telling me that `price` is private:

```
**note: declared private here
     float price;**
```

```
**error: ‘float Product::price’ is private within this context
     this->price = price;**
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess som parts of the code is missing. I cannot see, where price is defined.

Comment: are you talking about `float price` inside the constructor?

Comment: @DarkSide77
yes

Comment: you need to move the `float price` under the `public:` cuz in c++ the default value is private

Comment: The default visibility in `class` is `private`, so `Product::price` is private. Inheriting `Product` publicly doesn't change this, it just determines, if other classes can use the relationship between `Product` and `PerishableProduct`

Comment: member data `price` in class `Product` should be defined as `protected`, otherwise you cannot set its value from derived classes of `Product` like `PerishableProduct`

Comment: You should write `Product(price)`, not `Product(float())` followed by an assignment to `price`. (You should also initialize `expirationDate` in the initalizer list and not assign to it.)

Comment: I made some edits so that the question might be fit to be reopened. Nevertheless, I suspect that this question is a duplicate, and while I couldn't find the appropriate dupe target, I encourage anyone who finds it to close as duplicate instead. If there is no duplicate and it is reopened, the info given here in the comments by DarkSide77, fabian, Giogre, and molbdnilo should be made into answers.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong?

The **problem** is that `price` data member is a `private` data member of the base class `Product`. This means that it cannot be accessed directly by its derived classes or users of that base class etc. That is, the **assignment** `this->price = price;` cannot be done in the derived class' constructor.

To **solve** this you should use *member initializer list* to **initialize** price data member by using the base class constructor as shown below:

```
PerishableProduct::PerishableProduct(float price, const Date& expirationDate)
//------------vvvvv-------------------------------------->pass price here
    : Product(price), expirationDate(expirationDate) 
{
     //no need for assignment here
}
```